# Can Windows 10 be Test-Driven using Virtual Box?

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10

I, like many, have been offered to upgrade to Windows 10.

1. Can I download an ISO of Windows 10 and upgrade later?
2. Can I download an ISO of Windows 10 and put in on Virtual Box using a Windows 7 host?

Comment: Sure can, you can even install it without entering a key, use it unactivated for as long as you like, it will have reduced functionality this way, but nothing too serious. Free upgrade ends this July, one year from when rtm rolled out.

Comment: I like to have backup copies of the O/S in case I need to reinstall from scratch.  Typical upgrades require installation of the original (Win7) O/S and then an upgrade.  Is this true for Win 10?

Comment: Version 1511 allows you to enter the previous OS product key to install, if your bios has the product key stored there the Windows 10 installer will pick that up at time of install, so you can now do a clean install on bare metal. Once Windows 10 is activated it sends a hardware profile to Microsoft for storage, so if you ever have to reinstall it will activate automatically without hassle when it hits the activation servers.

Comment: Using in a Virtual Box is another thing getting it activated without a key,

Comment: Windows 10 can be used on any machine that supports it both physical and virtual.  You are allowed a single instance of Windows 10 per eligible license you have. If you don't want to pay for the upgrade it must be done before July 29th 2016 otherwise, the upgrade will not be free, and you will not have an copy of Windows 10 that can be activated.  Your qustions by the way have been asked multiple times here.  A little research is expected before asking a question.

Comment: Sorry... I tried to research the answer and did not come up with anything but answers that indicated S/W issues with Virtual Box, not licensing issues.

Comment: Both of those questions are answered on Microsoft's Windows 10 website.

Answer (score -1):

1. **No**. Technically, you can easily, but it would not be an official activated version, and it might or might not work indefinitely.
2. **No**. Technically you can easily. But again, it would be an inactivated, unlicensed copy, etc., same as 1.

Both cases, you would violate Microsoft License conditions, which is considered illegal in most places.

Comment: Seems you can download Windows 10 onto USB or get an ISO.  It is up to me if I have enough licenses.  Aren't licenses per CPU?  Virtual Box has the same CPU as the host.  Seems legal to me.  Is it *explicitly* prohibited?

Comment: Yes, sure. My point is the license you are deferring the upgrade on is not usable for that. If you happen to have bought further license keys, you could apply them.

Comment: The machine Windows 10 will detect will be the physical machine, since the virtual machine, will identical to the physical machine itself.  How do I know this?  Microsoft actually talks about how Windows 10 handles virtual machines in a blog.

Comment: @Ramhound, that would mean that the security of the virtual is completely violated - code inside the VM is not supposed to be able to look at outside the VM.

Comment: What are you talking about?  I never even hinted that would be the case.